# How to write a java program without using "class" keyword?

Tags: java

is there any possible way, or we cannot write any because as we can see everthing in java starts with only using class?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: just wondering if enum is useful just like this:

public enum NoClass { 
Baba, Java; 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
System.out.println("Hello Java Lovers "); 
} 
}

Comment: Actually, that...quite possibly would work.  But why didn't you just plug that into a compiler and _try it?_

Answer (score 2):

No, all code in Java programs *must* be contained within a class.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  You totally can, which the OP figured out, but didn't bother to mention in the question.

```
enum Main {
    FOO, BAR;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

[works just fine.](http://ideone.com/a7Dxlk)

Original answer:

You can't...but that may change in Java 8, when you'll be allowed to add static methods to interfaces.  I *think* Java 8 would allow you to write

```
interface Foo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ...
   }
}
```

but I'd need to double-check, and the answer to that may be in flux.

Comment: But you probably couldn't make an interface the entry point of your application, so that's a bit of a moot point.

Comment: ...Probably not, but I wouldn't rule out the possibility.  (There probably isn't a hard answer one way or the other yet.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman do you know any reasoning behind this ? I am not seeing the usefulness of this feature. Just to say, 'If I implement this interface, I get all these methods'?

Comment: I wouldn't think of it in those terms; rather, I would think of it as making sure you don't have to separate out an interface from all the static methods associated with it, like `Collection` and `Collections` in the JDK.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean that a class would have to implement an interface to have access to static methods? That seems convoluted.

Comment: Of course not; you'd call it like you normally call static methods already: `Foo.bar()`, except `Foo` can be an interface or a class.  It'd just let you put the static methods in a different place.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen i would have needed static methods in interfaces, i solved it using reflection which checked whether the parent, has a specific static method implemented.

Comment: @AlexWien: why would you ever do something like that?  Anytime you have a `Foo foo`, and you call `foo.bar()` when `bar` is a static method from the `Foo` class, that is always _exactly_ equivalent to just saying `Foo.bar()`.  That's no different between classes, abstract classes, or interface.

Comment: @LouisWasserman the point us that there is no static inheritance in Java , but i needed that.

Comment: @LouisWasserman The enum still gets compiled into a class. This is what the bytecode looks like: Compiled from "Main.java"
final class Main extends java.lang.Enum<Main> {
  public static final Main FOO;
  public static final Main BAR;
  public static Main[] values();
  public static Main valueOf(java.lang.String);
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  static {}; (Sorry for formatting)

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: Oh, of course.  But it fulfills the OP's requirements of "not using the class keyword."